# Return first occurring 2nd largest value in data frame rows using colnames & apply

Tags: r

Consider i have a df

```
> editor
          A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
User1     1  0  5  6  5  6  5  6  2  6
User2     0  5  4  6  4  5  5  1  7  5
```

I want to store the column name of the first occuring 2nd largest value in above rows.
Expected results

```
> editor
          A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  2nd_highest
User1     1  0  5  6  5  6  5  6  2  6      C
User2     0  5  4  6  4  5  5  1  7  5      D
```

i tried `edited$2nd_highest <- colnames(edited)[apply(edited, 1, which.max)+1]` but did'nt worked well .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea. We first sort the `unique` values of each row and extract the second value. Since we specify `decreasing = TRUE`, then the second value will be the second highest. We then use the first value of each element of the new list as the index for the column names

```
ind_lst <- apply(df, 1, function(i) which(i == sort(unique(i), decreasing = TRUE)[2]))
df$highest.two <- names(df)[unlist(lapply(ind_lst, '[', 1))]
df
#      A B C D E F G H I J highest.two
#User1 1 0 5 6 5 6 5 6 2 6           C
#User2 0 5 4 6 4 5 5 1 7 5           D
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was getting some weird results so I was double checking.

Comment: ahh... Thanks @David. Didn't know that `T` is frowned upon :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an attempt to achieve this using algebra in order to keep it vectorized and avoid by row operations (though it still does a matrix conversion similar to `apply`). The idea here is to find the maximum- then reduce it from the data set, then convert to `log` (after multiplying by -1) which will result in the largest value becoming `-Inf` (meaning the smallest value) and then do `1/result` in order to find the largest value out of the values left.

```
indx <- max.col(1/log((editor - editor[cbind(1:nrow(editor), 
                max.col(editor))]) * -1), ties.method = "first")
names(editor)[indx]
# [1] "C" "D"
```

Comment: I guess the double `max.col` should be efficient enough. Similar to this would be: (1) `mat = as.matrix(editor)` to avoid converting twice to "matrix" later, (2) `mat[mat == mat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)), max.col(mat, "first"))]] = min(mat)` to keep the (as it seems) "integer" nature of data (`Inf` is inherently "double") and (3) `colnames(mat)[max.col(mat, "first")]` the second `max.col` after eliminating the "max"es in each row.

Comment: @alexis_laz I've actually thought about all of your points. Regarding the first point - (you already thought me this once) but I was just too lazy. Regarding the other two points I was trying to do this without changing the original data set. Though I like your suggestions in general.

Answer (score 2):

This can help you:

```
mat <- matrix(sample(1:8, 24, replace=TRUE), ncol=6)
mat
sec_highest <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x[which(x != max(x))])))
LETTERS[sec_highest] # letters display
```

Note that if you have two second highests with same scores, only one will be displayed.

Comment: [the 3rd line] - It searches for every line of the matrix, the index (i.e. here the column number) of the element who matches the max element of the line (after removing its max element, so the second highest element).
Then use `colnames(mat)[sec_highest]` (which in my example will be be NULL) to create the columns of letters you displayed in your example.